# Are there magic knight tours on a $6\times6$ or $10\times10$ board?

Tags: combinatorics, magic-square, knight-tours

In mathworld, magic tour, it is mentioned that for odd $n$, only semimagic knight
tours are possible on a $n\times\ n$ - board.

For $n = 8$, it has been verified that there are no magic knight tours, only semimagic ones.

What about  $6\times6$ and $10\times10$ ?
Are there magic knight tours on these boards ?

The case $n = 6$ should be feasible with brute force, but I have no idea how to
enumerate the tours efficiently.

Comment: Additional question : Is there a semimagic tour on any $n\ x\ n$-board, if $n\ge 5$ ?

Comment: At http://magictour.free.fr it says, "Jan.2009 Awani Kumar has enumerated over 3000 semi-magic knight's tours 
on 10x10 board achieving 75% magic ratio, the highest on any 
singly-even board till date." It gives a link to the 10 x 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no magic knight tours on $6 \times 6$ or $10 \times 10$ boards.  On this web page from George Jelliss : http://www.mayhematics.com/t/mg.htm, we see "Theorem 4. A magic knight's tour is impossible on a board with singly-even sides." (Here, "singly even" means a number of the form $2k$, where $k$ is odd.)

Now, Jelliss's definition of a magic knight tour differs from MathWorld's definition -- MathWorld requires the diagonals to add up to the same constant as the rows and columns do, while George Jelliss's definition does not.  However, any magic tour satisfying the MathWorld definition would satisfy the other definition.  So there are no magic knight tours on $6 \times 6$ or $10 \times 10$ boards.

Edit: As noted in the comment below, the answer to "Is there a semimagic tour on any $n \times n$-board, if $n≥5$ ?" is "no".

Comment: Since I mean with "semimagic" what Jelliss means with "magic", you answered my additional question with a clear no.  Is anything known about the case m single even, n double even ( or vice versa ) , for example $4 \times 6$ or $6 \times 8$

Comment: And finally, what about the $4\times 8$-case ?